# Averaging program compiles but gives bad result

Tags: c

I was writing a C program that takes as many numbers as you want and finds the average of all of them. This was just something I was doin for fun and to test out how good I was doing so far into learning C. However, after debugging and compiling the program, I tested out the code and it didn't work. I gave it the amount of numbers it would be working with and it gave a seemingly random number as output without even asking what the numbers were. The number it gave me is: 6422356. The code I wrote is below, do you know what might be causing this? I'm using notepad++ and MinGW compiler.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int nums;
    printf("Averagerator Machinerator! \n");
    printf("How many numbers are in this average? \n");
    scanf("%d", &nums);
    getchar();
    int whilst;
    int current[nums + 1];
    while (whilst ==! nums+1) {
        printf("A number, please: \n");
        scanf("%d", &current[whilst]);
        whilst = whilst + 1;
    };
    getchar();
    int average;
    int ncurrent;
    while (ncurrent ==! nums + 1) {
        average = average + current[ncurrent];
        ncurrent = ncurrent + 1;
    };
    getchar();
    printf("%d", average, "is your average. \n");
    getchar();
    return 0;
    
}
```

I tried to look in my program for possible issues, adding getchar()'s wherever necessary to test, and couldn't find anything that might yield such a bizarre answer.

Comment: `int whilst;` is not initialized, so initial value is just random one, set it to 0

Comment: btw, average is `sum/count`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while (whilst ==! nums+1) {
```

shouldn't that be:

```
while (whilst != nums+1) {
```

What you are doing now is taking the boolean `not` of `nums+1` and then trying to compare to whatever random value is in whilst.

BTW:  You need to initialize those local variables with values or you will have some strange bugs.

Comment: `!nums + 1` evaluates as `(!nums) + 1`, yielding 1 or 2 depending on the value in `nums`.

Comment: I always get my order of operations mixed up.  That's why I'm glad parenthesis are free when I write my code.